# How to get param from url in angular 4?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get startdate from the URL. 
The URL looks like `http://sitename/booking?startdate=28-08-2017`

My code is below:

aap.module.ts

```js
    import {...};

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent, ModalComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        JsonpModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([{
                path: '',
                component: AppComponent
            },
        ]),    
      ], 
      providers: [ContactService, AddonService, MainService],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

aap.component.ts

```js
import {...}
import {Router, ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';

constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
  // subscribe to router event
  this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
    console.log(params);
  });

}
```

But its giving the below error

> Unhandeled Promise rejection: No base href set. Please provide a value
>   for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base element to the document. ;
>   Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: No base href set.
>   Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base
>   element to the document.

How does Angular know the base href?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router#the-basics

Answer (score 173, accepted):

**Update**

I belive Dimitry Grinko's answer in this post is better than this one.

**Old answer**

This should do the trick retrieving the params from the url:

```js
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
  this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        let date = params['startdate'];
        console.log(date); // Print the parameter to the console. 
    });
}
```

The local variable date should now contain the *startdate* parameter from the URL. The modules Router and Params can be removed (if not used somewhere else in the class).

Comment: this answer is work, but why after refreshing the page that have parameter on url will make the page become blank?

Comment: Hard to tell. The first thing that comes to my mind is that you maybe are navigating in the ngOnInit section of the typescript code without providing any parameters? Then it will naturally go back to the component without any params.

Comment: Hello @Curiosity_is_Learning I am trying to set the query params as a global variable. Currently with this logic "date" is only available within this subscribe method right? How to keep those query params value as a global variable. I tried let.date =['startdate'] but when calling it anywhere outside of the subscribe method, it is undefined.

Comment: hi @Jesse, this should be rather simple. Just declare a variable in the top of your Anulgar component like this: `private startDate: string;` then you should be able to replace the `let date =  params['startdate'];` with `this.startDate = params['startdate'];`. Then you  can reuse the variable elsewhere in the component as much as you like, simply by calling `this.startDate`

Comment: @Curiosity_is_Learning That is exactly what I did, but once I am calling "this.startDate" outside of the subscribe method. The value is undefined. Inside the subscribe method "this.startDate" prints out the proper date.

Comment: Hm... strange. Here is my working example I just made. Can you see any differences? The `clickTest` function is called from HTML code that i have not pasted here, and it is then logging to the console

https://gist.github.com/ertkjern/1af7c3fc9d4a225159fd17c9f6cf655e

Answer (score 267):

**Routes**

```js
export const MyRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '/items/:id', component: MyComponent }
]
```

**Component**

```js
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
public id: string;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
   this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
}
```

Comment: This answer works better than the accepted one in my case. Thanks!

Comment: If i want to send one object and don't want to show that in url then what i can do ?

Comment: @Anuj Use service

Comment: My Requirement is not like that , I want to click on one table and send that table data to other page which have 4-5 fields .

Comment: @Anuj yes, you can use service for it. onClick(row: any) { this.shareService.setData(row); this.router.navigate(['/page2'])} and in your page2 you can get this data ngOnInit() { const data = this.shareService.getData(); } Hope it helps

Comment: Looking Great. Thanks for help , Actually i m new in angular 4 . One more qn is that how we will define that  shareService. It is silly qn but currently i don't know flow of it bez i was working in ionic 2/3.

Comment: @Anuj It is the same approach as ionic 2/3

Comment: Which is best practice between `this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('x')` and `this.route.snashop.params.x` ?

Comment: really helpful .easy and exact solution  than other

Comment: @Ben But if you want same page routing, you have to use the accepted answer. Let's say you are browsing through a list of detail pages that are accessed by an id from the url. in that case, you have to subscribe to the ActivatedRoute to detect the current id from the url. The snapshot is only for one time access.

Comment: @Dejazmach This is a good answer about different between the Snapshot and Observable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53242610/6108211

Comment: @TobiasKaufmann https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455734/how-to-get-query-parameters-from-url-in-angular-5

Comment: It should be this._route.snapshot. **queryParamMap** .get, not paramMap! That got me stuck for a while.

Comment: @Tony The question was about Angular 4. If you have a solution for another Angular version feel free to add your answer, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 31):

In angular, They separate it into 2 kind of url.

1. URL pattern `/heroes/:limit`. Example: `/heroes/20`

   - You can get raw value by using `route.snapshot.paramMap.get`.
   - Subscribe from `route.paramMap` to get params
2. URL pattern `/heroes`. Example: `/heroes?limit=20`

   - You can get raw value by using `route.snapshot.queryParamMap`

Reference: [All you need to know about Angular parameters](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/all-you-need-to-know-about-angular-parameters-309828b30826?source=friends_link&sk=6e3a6e18a102170f5aa5c322c40d7c79)

Answer (score 26):

```js
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(paramsId => {
        this.id = paramsId.id;
        console.log(this.id);
    });
  
 }
```

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion for angular 5. Thank you!

Comment: Can't observable be resolved on next eventloop frame with undefined in console?

Comment: This gives me "undefined"

Comment: This also gives me "undefined". For some reason, I am suspecting that this issue is happening on "ngOnInit". When I created another method and performed (console.log(this.id) I am able to see the proper data. But having console.log exactly where you have it in your answer; I received an undefined in the console.

Comment: I edited this, my bad :D  it was giving you undefined because at the moment the console log happened the data from subscribe was not received. (Don't do it like that :D, I was a beginner at that time), to test the value, try to put it in the same function scope.

Answer (score 13):

**`app.module.ts`**

```
import { Routes,RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
    { 
       path: '', 
       component: HomeComponent 
    }
    { 
       path: '/users/:id/:name', 
       component: UsersComponent 
    }
]

@NgModule({
   ....
   imports : [
       .......,
       RouterModule.appRoot(routes)
   ]
   ....
})
```

**Component Page**

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
    user : {id: number, name: string};

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        // If you get param one time in page use below code...
        this.user = {
            id : this.route.snapshot.params['id'],
            name : this.route.snapshot.params['name']   
        };
        // Dynamically change params use below code...
        this.route.params.subscribe((param : Params) => {
            this.user.id = param['id'];
            this.user.name = param['name'];
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This one worked for me in 2022 with Angular 14. Not the accepted answer, I guess something has changed in Angular API: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45998138/8784518

Comment: This answer works for me with Angular: 15.2.3

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer uses the observable to retrieve the parameter which can be useful in the parameter will change throughtout the component lifecycle.

If the parameter will not change, one can consider using the [params](https://angular.io/api/router/Params) object on the snapshot of the router url.

`snapshot.params` returns all the parameters in the URL in an object.

```js
constructor(private route: ActivateRoute){}

ngOnInit() {
   const allParams = this.route.snapshot.params // allParams is an object
   const param1 = allParams.param1 // retrieve the parameter "param1"
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Check parameters from URL string or as `:param` in your routeConfig

**downstream.component.ts**

```js
...
import {Router,ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
...    
export class DownstreamComponent  {
    constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
) {
    if(this.route.snapshot.queryParams) 
      console.log(this.route.snapshot.params); // e.g. :param1 in routeConfig
    if(this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('param1'))
      console.log(this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('param1')); // e.g. in URI ?param1=blah
}

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```js
this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(x => {
    let id = x.get('id');
    console.log(id);  
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
import {Router, ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';

constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap
    .subscribe( params => {
    let id = +params.get('id');
    console.log('id' + id);
    console.log(params);


id12
ParamsAsMap {params: {…}}
keys: Array(1)
0: "id"
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
params:
id: "12"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
        }
        )

      }
```

Answer (score 3):

try this one.
if your URL param is like http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/?startdate=12-02-2022

```
const date = this.ActivatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('startdate'); 
console.warn(date)
```

Answer (score 2):

**use `paramMap`**

This will provide param names and their values

```js
//http://localhost:4200/categories/1
//{ path: 'categories/:category', component: CategoryComponent },

import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {

  this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
        console.log(params)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps someone. In case that u get undefined while doing this with something that's not "id", check if u are passing right parameter:

If your route in parent-component.ts is:

```
 onSelect(elem) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl(`/element/${elem.type}`);
  }
```

And in child-component.ts

```
  type: string;
  elem: ElemModel;

  constructor(
    private elemService: ElemService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe((data) => {

      console.log(data);  // 'data' will give u an object with the type inside, check the 
      name of that type inside console of devTool, as u will put that name inside 
      data[HERE] down below.

      this.type = data["elem-type-maybe"]; // Don't do this.type = data["type"], do 
      data[NAME] as said above.

      this.elem = this.elemService.getElem(this.type); // getElem is method in service 
      which returns that specific type.
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this for get startdate from given your booking URL route parameter:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero',
  templateUrl: './hero.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hero.component.css']
})
export class HeroComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute) { 
    this.activeRoute.queryParams.subscribe((qp) => {
      console.log('Get Router Params:', this.activeRoute.snapshot.queryParams.startdate);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

For route URL related more information you can go through [here](https://kknebulatech.blogspot.com/2021/07/how-to-get-full-url-for-route-in-angular.html)