# How can I extract the id from the url?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, single-page-application

The url looks like this:

```
http://localhost:4200/room/RECd4teOsdsro9YRcOMX/chat
```

I'm trying to extract the id part `(RECd4teOsdsro9YRcOMX)`

I tried the following:

```
chatRoomUid: string;

constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute
) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.chatRoom$ = this.route.parent.parent.params.pipe(
      tap(params => this.chatRoomUid = params.chatRoomUid),
      switchMap(params => {
        if (!params.chatRoomUid) return of(null);
        this.chatRoomUid = params.chatRoomUid;
      })
    );

    console.log(this.chatRoomUid); // returns undefined
}
```

How can I extract the id from the url and save it to my variable `chatRoomUid`?

Route:

```
{ path: 'room/:roomUid', loadChildren: () => import('@chatapp/pages/room/room.module').then(m => m.RoomModule) },
```

Edit: Added the routes

Comment: How does your route look like? It should look something like this: `{path: 'room/:chatRoomUid/chat', component: ChatComponent}` see https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration

Comment: Please add the routes in your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get param from url in angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997369/how-to-get-param-from-url-in-angular-4)

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997369/how-to-get-param-from-url-in-angular-4/47382088

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're `console.log`ing in a different context.
Remember `Observable`s are asynchronous, thus you'd have to move `console.log` inside `switchMap`.

However, just produce a new `Observable`

```
chatRoomUid$: Observable<string>;

...

this.chatRoomUid$ = this.route.params.pipe(
  map(params => params['roomUid'])
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define your route like this

```
{path: 'room/:chatRoomUid/chat', component: ChatComponent}
```

Then in your component simply

```
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute){}

ngOnInit(){
    this.route.params.subscribe( params =>
        console.log(params['chatRoomUid']);
    )
}
```