# Angular 7 - Get Param Value from the url

Tags: angular7

I already went through link: [How to get param from url in angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997369/how-to-get-param-from-url-in-angular-4) and trying to follow the same approach.

I am using ***Angular 7*** and my current URL: `http://localhost:4200/student-details/488`

When I clicked on different Side Pane link, I want to get the value 488 and pass that value to other component.

I used below in ngOnit() where my page is routing to.

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
   console.log('params', params);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your routing module has something similar to below -

```
{
    path: 'student-details/:id',
    component: StudentDetailsComponent,
}
```

You can get the `488` (`:id`) property from `student-details/488` like -

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
   let id = params.get('id');
   // let id = +params.get('id'); //<--- if you want to convert it into a numeric value
   console.log('Student Id', id);
});
```

Comment: `console.log('Student Id', id);`, why not to use `console.log('Student Id'+ id);`

Comment: In current example, both would output the same. `,` based `console.log` is useful when you are printing a javascript object. Using `,` operator will allow you to inspect the object in console.

Comment: `this.route.paramMap` not giving me any value actually from detailed Page, I want to pass StudentId to other component, so that using Student Id I want to show other details

Comment: Unable to pass Id to other components

Comment: can you provide the code for your routing module and your component where you're trying to access the property. Also, a quicker way to help you fix the issue would be to create a minimum reproducible scenario at https://stackblitz.com

Comment: Now I want to redirect it to `{
path: 'member',
loadChildren: './member/member.module#MemberModule'
}`

Answer (score 0):

I am using angular 8

**Component from where I am routing**

```
this.router.navigate(['/ledger-card'], { queryParams: { branchId: '10', loanAcc: '2738'}});
```

**Component where I am receiving the routed data**

```
const param = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap;
    if  (param.get('branchId')) {
      const branchId =  param.get('branchId');
      const loanAcc = param.get('loanAcc');
    }
```

** Make sure you import ActivatedRoute

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

Comment: How to send Id to other component(s) which is independent of other component ?

Answer (score 0):

**Routing Module:**

```
  ...
  {
    path: '',
    component: YourListComponent
  },
  {                                  // 
    path: ':id',                     // <-- 
    component: YourSingleComponent   // <-- 
  }                                  // 
  ...
```

**yoursingle.component.ts**

```
...

import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
...

export class YourSingleComponent implements OnInit {
    ...

    singleID: number;
    ...

    constructor(
        private _route: ActivatedRoute,
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.singleID = parseInt(this._route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id"));
    }

    ...
}
```