# Angular: How to read a parameter in the URL string when opening the start page?

Tags: angular, url, start-page

How to read a parameter in the URL string when opening the start page? If I pass the ID to the URL: mysite.com/productid, and the app will read and remember this ID for future reference ?
I want to read the QR-code, which contains the path with ID of the product and go directly to the site to this product section.

Comment: Refer this stackoerflow answer-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997369/how-to-get-param-from-url-in-angular-4

Comment: thanks, that was useful

Answer (score 0):

**First Create A route in app-routing module file like this**

```
{path: 'test/:id', component: TestComponent}
```

**and get id in your Start Component like this and store in local storage**

```
constructor(
private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute
) {}

ngOnInit() { 
const getidfromurl = this.activeRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
localStorage.setItem('my id',getidfromurl);
}
```

Comment: Thanks  Mohammed Aamier