# Get URL parameters in Angular

Tags: angular, routes

I'm trying the get the url parameters in angular 
i've tried

```
 ngOnInit() {   

   this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
     console.log("test1",params)
}) 
//and
console.log("test2", this.route.snapshot.params)

 }
ngAfterViewInit(){


}
```

The response it get : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2ow7.png)

Comment: Hi, have a look at [this] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997369/how-to-get-param-from-url-in-angular-4). Also can you provide how you pass the params?

Comment: The second log should be `this.route.snapshot.paramMap` instead of `.params`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
constructor() {
    const query = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
    console.log(query.get('param_key')); // www.google.com?size=123 --- param_key is size here

}
```

Try out this and let me know if missing anything ... Happy coding ... :)

Comment: @SoufianChaoui you are using the wrong key, check out this...

 this.route.queryParams.subscribe(
            params => {
                console.log(params[param_key]);
            }
        )

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ActivatedRouter class or Router class?
When router is of class Router then this should work.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

...
constructor(private router: Router) {
     this.router.params.subscribe(params => {
     console.log('my parameters: ', params);
    });
}
```