# Angular access routing parameter from parent

Tags: angular

I have this Routing:

```
{ path: 'item/:id',
  component: parentComponent,
  children: [
    { path: 'edit', component: childComponent }
  ]
}
```

To navigate to this Location I use this:

```
this.router.navigate(['/item/' + item.id + '/edit']);
```

Now my Question is:

How can now my childComponent know the id? What Code do I need to get the id in the child.component.ts? (parentComponent also Needs to know the id, thats why I dont have the Parameter at the end)

Comment: This has been answered already here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45998138/11719787

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the child component you can add the following line.

You need to target the parent route snapshot because the current snapshot is the current route, which is the child component

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  this.id = this.route.parent.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
  console.log('got the id', this.id);
}
```

Or if you want to subscribe the param in the child component you can use instead

```
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.parent.params.subscribe(params => console.log('params id', params.id));
  }
```

Comment: Is there a way to subscribe it? I subscribe it in my parent component with: `this.route.params.subscribe(params => (this.id = params.id))`

Comment: in child component try the following,


this.route.parent.params.subscribe(params => (this.id = params.id));