# Angular 6 QueryParams Not available OnInit?

Tags: angular, angular-activatedroute

Okay so I am creating a simple page which i want the user to pass in a bunch of parameters via the URL.  The very basic example I have been using is http://localhost:4200/?client_id=test

I am following all the procedures I can find on the internet but for some reason the parameters aren't available OnInit, and are only available via subscription?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'Login';
  submitted: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute){
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.route.snapshot.queryParams); //line 26
    this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(this.route.snapshot.queryParams); //line 28
    })
  }
}
```

this is what prints

```
{} - line 26
{} - line 28
{client_id: "test"} - line 28
```

Its as if Angular isn't recognizing the query string parameters until after the page loads?  How can i get around this?

Edit:

Ive tried using params.get() also - same result

```
this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(params => {
  console.log(params.get('client_id'));
})
```

prints

```
null
test
```

so the first activation of the subscription the value is null - then the value changes to test and its updated.  I'm trying to avoid the first "null" value.

Comment: have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997369/how-to-get-param-from-url-in-angular-4

Comment: I have tried that it still gives me an undefined/null value first, then updates to the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
this.route.params.subscribe((params:Params) => {
    ... use params['key'] to access its value
});
```

in my opinion, the best approach is to use subscription and do like this :

[image]

Comment: I have tried this also - still gives a null value, then the proper value. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

and try this one ...

```
@Component(/* ... */)
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
    id$: Observable<string>;
    id: string;

    constructor(private route: ActivateRoute) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.id$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(map(paramMap => paramMap.get('id')));

        // or for sync ( one time ) retrieval of id

        this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post as text so it's easier to extract.

Answer (score 0):

both of these solutions are working if I try it:

```
 ngOnInit(){
    this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(params =>
        console.log(params.get("client_id"))
     );

    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params =>
        console.log(params["client_id"])
    );
 }
```